# Understanding grammar in 十一月十一号这一天是四个“一“在一起

Tags: grammar

Here is a sentence from the learning app that I use that I cannot *parse*:

十一月十一号这一天是四个“一“在一起

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

十一月十一号 means November 11th, that is, the date 11/11.

When you say "XX + 这/那 一  + classifier/noun phrase", you are just emphasizing that you are referring to XX. In this case, "十一月十一号这一天" just means the date 11/11. Normally it is used to disambiguate the function of that part within the sentence; for instance, if you don't use it in this sentence, the reader may think that 十一月十一号 refers to something happening on that date, instead of the date itself. Another usage example may be 琳娜这个名字很漂亮; it means "the name 琳娜 is beautiful".

十一月十一号这一天 is the subject of the sentence.

是 is the verb "to be". Up to now, we have "the date 11/11 is...".

The rest of the sentence is 四个“一“在一起. It has two parts:

- 四个“一“: four ones.
- 在一起: together

So the meaning is "the date 11/11 is four ones together".

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Topic/subject: [十一月十一号这一天] (the date, 11-11)

comment: 是四个“一“在一起 (is four "1" together)

The comment gives info on the topic:

Topic: *The date of 11th November*

comment: *it is made up of four "one" in Arabic numerals*

Answer (score 0):

> 十一月十一号这一天是四个“一“在一起

I think it meant 11/11 - There are four "ones" on the date of November Eleven.

It could be a phrase that comes out of a complete sentence such as:

(你注意到了嗎)十一月十一号这一天**是**(由)四个“一“(排列)在一起 - (Did you notice that) the date of November 11th **comes as** four "ones" (arranged) together.

Comment: Thank you. I know the meaning of each of the words separately but I don't understand why this sentence makes any sense grammatically.